# What is the point in combining sucralose and acesulfame potassium?

Tags: sweeteners

What is the point in combining the no-calorie, artificial sweeteners  [sucralose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sucralose) and [acesulfame potassium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acesulfame_potassium)?

I'm asking as I have seen some products doing so, e.g. [Optimum Nutrition Gold Standard 100% Whey Protein Powder, Extreme Milk Chocolate](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000QSTBNS):

> Ingredients: Protein Blend (Whey Protein Isolate, Whey Protein Concentrate, Whey Peptides), Cocoa (Processed with Alkali), Natural and Artificial Flavors, Lecithin, Creamer (Sunflower Oil, Maltodextrin, Modified Food Starch, Dipotassium Phosphate, Tricalcium Phosphate, Tocopherols), Salt, **Acesulfame Potassium**, Aminogen, **Sucralose**, Lactase.

Comment: Perhaps one is cheaper but gives an aftertaste in large quantities, or both do but it's not noticeable at low concentrations of each individually. Many additives have regulated maximum concentrations, but of course we don't know the concentrations in the product. So we may only be able to speculate

Comment: @ChrisH Thanks. I think with some expertise one can narrow down to a reasonably small set of speculations.